# How to extract hex color codes from a colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, colormap

From the below `branca` colormap

```
import branca

color_map = branca.colormap.linear.PuRd_09.scale(0, 250)

colormap = color_map.to_step(index=[0, 10, 20, 50, 70, 90, 120, 200])
```

[image]

How can I extract hex colours for all the steps(index) from the above `Branca` colormap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.colors.to_hex`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_hex.html#matplotlib.colors.to_hex) on `colormap.colors`:

```
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex

out = [to_hex(c) for c in colormap.colors]

# or
out = list(map(to_hex, colormap.colors))
```

Output:

```
['#f7f4f9', '#f0ebf4', '#e3d9eb', '#d0aad2', '#d084bf', '#e44199', '#67001f']
```

Comment: The question was specifically about how to extract colors from `branca` which may have a different structure than matplotlib

Comment: @SNygard and I believe my answer addresses the question, I only use matplotlib to convert the rgba tuple to hex. Also the question has a matplotlib tag

Comment: Got it! I misread your code the first time. I read (wrongly) that you were defining the colormap with matplotlib.